# Coding data and changing the column names in another columns using codes in R and tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

below, I have demonstrated part of my  data:

```
df<-read.table(text=" K G   M
12  2345    Gholi
KAM 2345    KAM
Noghl   1990    KAM
Zae 1990    441
12  2345    441
KAM 1990    12
Noghl   1800    12"

,header=TRUE)
```

I would like to make codes for  K, G and M and starting with 1. We have 4 groups in K, so 1,2,3 and 4. for G, start with 5, so 5, 6 and 7 as we have three subgroups.

Using the following codes, I will get the following table:

```
df = lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(as.factor(x)))
data.frame(Map("+", df, cumsum(c(0, head(sapply(df, max), -1)))))
```

I will get the following table:

```
KM  KN  KZ
1   7   10
2   7   11
3   6   11
4   6   9
1   7   9
2   6   8
3   5   8
```

Now I want to get the following table:

```html
Group C
K,M 1,8
K,M 2,11
K 3
K 4
G 7
G 6
M 10
M 9
```

For example, in Group, Column K (12), M (12,12) goes to Codes 1 and 8, as they coded in KM and KZ and so

Comment: sorry, you are right.

Comment: I have a doubt, are you removing the '5' because it is unique value in the transformed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting all the columns to integer values based on `factor` route, and adding the `max` value of previous columns to the current, we `pivot` to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, bind with the original column values reshaped to 'long' format,  grouped by the original value column 'origval', `paste` the `unique` elements of other columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
      mutate_all(~ as.integer(factor(.))) %>% 
      mutate(G = max(K) + G, M = max(G) + M) %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
      bind_cols(df %>% 
                  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
                  pivot_longer(everything(),values_to = 'origvalue') %>%
                  dplyr::select(-name)) %>% 
     group_by(origvalue) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~toString(unique(.))) %>%
     dplyr::select(Group = name, C = value)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#   Group C    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 K, M  1, 8 
#2 G     5    
#3 G     6    
#4 G     7    
#5 M     9    
#6 M     10   
#7 K, M  2, 11
#8 K     3    
#9 K     4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(K = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("12", 
"KAM", "Noghl", "Zae"), class = "factor"), G = c(2345L, 2345L, 
1990L, 1990L, 2345L, 1990L, 1800L), M = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("12", "441", "Gholi", "KAM"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: @User20100 Can you show your package versions.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.99.9000’
> packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Comment: WIth `dplyr`, I am using the devel version.  Just wanted to check on which step you are getting the error.  can you please run line by line i.e `df %>%
      mutate_all(~ as.integer(factor(.)))` if it works then do `df %>%
      mutate_all(~ as.integer(factor(.))) %>% 
      mutate(G = max(K) + G, M = max(G) + M) %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything())`

Comment: @User20100 Is this applied on the same data you showed in your post.  Can you check the `str(df)` for any `list` column

Comment: If your dplyr version is old, then there would be an issue

Comment: @User20100 You meant the `4, 10`?  The grouping was based. on the original values

Comment: I find in the original it is `Zae` and `Gholi` so, it is not matching for 'K', 'M'

Comment: @User20100 I am not finding any difference in your update except the order of rows.  In my output, I have `K, M` for `1, 8` and `2, 11` same as yours, `K` is 3, 4, same as yours, `M` is 10, 9